# How do I use a traditional Chinese font in css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display some text in traditional Chinese on my site ie

HTML:

```
<div id = "shareText">好</div>
```

CSS:

```
#shareText
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 125px;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    color: #a9a4a4;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

However the output character I'm getting is: å¥½. I tired changing the font like this:

```
#shareText
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 125px;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    color: #a9a4a4;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: "微軟正黑體", "Microsoft JhengHei",  Tahoma , Verdana , Arial , sans-serif;
}
```

However the character remains the same. What am I doing wrong? Is it something to do with the coding of the html file? I tried changing from unicode 8 to 16, the character appears but I lose all formatting, all my divs are in the wrong place..

Comment: whats the char-encoding of the html ?

Comment: Have you add meta tag for character encoding?

Comment: no, not added a meta tag, what should I add?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This displays correctly for me. Note the `<meta charset="utf-8" />` tag in the head.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Chinese</title>

    <style>
#shareText{

    position: absolute;
    right:125px;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    color: #a9a4a4;
   font-size: 25px;
}   
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "shareText">好</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For traditional chinese,

You have to use, `<html lang="zh-Hant">`

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-Hant">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Chinese</title>

    <style>
#shareText{

    position: absolute;
    right:125px;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    color: #a9a4a4;
   font-size: 25px;
}   
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "shareText">好</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: I ran above code, it works fine.